# IntelliJ: Go to the start of the last command in Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

I run a program using the Terminal in IntelliJ (and sometimes Konsole on KDE).

Wondering if there's a shortcut or method to get to the top of a recently run command. I have a lot of output and the debug text at the top of that output. There's no way to reverse this.

Is there a hotkey to do the same thing but with folder structures? i.e. go to top of the 'current folder view' on the left panel.

Thanks.

Comment: Feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Great job on the IDE my friend. I just wish it weren't so expensive.